# How to call a function on tag remove in AngularJS ngInputTags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tags

How can I call a function when I remove a tag? I tried various methods to do so but none worked. Can anyone one suggest help.

```
<tags-input ng-model="vm.studentObj.assigned_employees" display-property="name" >
</tags-input>
<p ng-bind="employee"></p>
```

Comment: what do you mean by tag remove ?

Comment: when i remove a tag by clicking cross-mark

Comment: so then click on cross mark is your event

Comment: Yes but i am able to decriment my array but not calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Syntax:

```
<tags-input
  ng-model="{string}"
  [on-tag-removing="{expression}"]
  [on-tag-removed="{expression}"]
  [on-tag-clicked="{expression}"]>
</tags-input>
```

where:
[onTagRemoving] can be described as an Expression that will be invoked before removing a tag. The tag is available as $tag. This method must return either a boolean value or a promise.

[onTagRemoved] is an Expression to evaluate upon removing an existing tag. The removed tag is available as $tag.

[onTagClicked] is an Expression to evaluate upon clicking an existing tag. The clicked tag is available as $tag.

In the end, now it's on you how you needs to fire an event.